# How to select a 2.4GHz chip antenna for a space-constrained environment?

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, pcb-antenna

I need to use the DA14580 BLE chip for my project. The problem is for the antenna. The reference design provided for the antenna is only PCB trace that's is too big for my project:

[image: example PCB trace antenna for DA14580]

I don't know how to choose a chip antenna instead. The DA14580 need to communicate with my smartphone, as a wearable. So the distance is not really big.

I see that some device use the DA14580 with chip antenna, but I don't find any information about the antennas used for.

I think of using this chip (even if a little big) :

> ANT-2.45-CHP-x

[image: Schematic of DA14580 with antenna]

Do you think that will work ?

How to choose a chip antenna for BLE ?

Comment: Search for 2.4GHz chip antenna - many are specifically for BLE.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EE.SE! Currently, your question is a [off topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since you're looking for specific purchasing suggestions. **However**, I think this would be a great canonical question for `How to select a 2.4GHz chip antenna for a space-constrained environment?`. If you want to edit your question to be more general, this would be a great way to do it and a valuable question for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Digikey has plenty to search through - I'm afraid you'll just have to use their parametric search to figure out what works best for you.  On a more general note, Texas Instruments has a nice guide for understanding some of the different antenna topologies that are out there:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra161b/swra161b.pdf

If you can fit it, I really like the "Inverted-F" and they even provide the footprint to make layout easy.  The "Meandered Inverted-F" antenna might be a good bet for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog recommends PCB antenna specially for DA14580 chip due to performance issues (as per link below). 
https://support.dialog-semiconductor.com/forums/post/dialog-smartbond-bluetooth-low-energy-42-%E2%80%93-hardware-device-reference-designs/chip

They may be indicating that efficiency of PCB antenna is higher then Chip Antenna.However you can test it using Johanson 2450AT18A100 for your requirement.